# search database and displaying result in android (it's not working )

Tags: android, database

This is my function in the Database class and it's closing my app when clicking on the search button:

```
public String search(String r) {
 String result = "";
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 String query = "SELECT _Name,_City,_Job  FROM " + TABLE_Person + " WHERE _Job LIKE '" + r + "'";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
 c.moveToFirst();

 while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
  if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Job")) == r) {
   result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Name"));
   result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_City"));
   result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Job"));
  }
  c.moveToNext();
 }

 db.close();

 return result;
}
```

Comment: can you post the crash trace message ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Use `equals()` method to check the two strings have the same value.

```
  while(c.moveToNext()){

    if(r.equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Job"))){
        result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Name"));
        result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_City"));
        result += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_Job"));

    }
```